# Issue with service dynamism and blueprint

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi, declarative-services

I have a non-blueprint bundle which provides a service via Declarative Service annotations.

I have another bundle, using blueprint, which contains a optional reference for this service and then injects this reference into a number of declared beans.

Starting up both within a Karaf container, the service is registered and the blueprint bundle can access it and use as intended. The configuration for the service providing bundle can be updated, and it is unbound and rebound again to the blueprint bundle which is perfect.

However, when the service providing bundle is restarted, or updated, the service is unbound but never rebound to the using bundle, so that the proxy object held by the blueprint reference never resolves to the service reference.

Sometimes restarting the blueprint bundle will fix this, but usually it requires a full framework restart to get it working again.

I do not get the same behavior when a non-blueprint bean is consuming the service via declarative services.

Has anyone had any similar issues with using a mix of DS and blueprint to provide/consume services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blueprint is not dynamic. It has a "damping" proxy which tries to wallpaper over service dynamism but does not always provide what is needed. In general, I would always use DS over Blueprint.